How do I use node-opcua when deploying an app with IIS?
I am trying to read value from an opcua server in my sveltekit app using node-opcua. I can successfully connect and read the values from my dev machine but when I deploy the app on IIS I get the error below
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\node-opcua-default-nodejs\Config\PKI'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1373:26)
    at mkdir (C:\inetpub\AreaTracking\wwwroot\build\node_modules\node-opcua-pki\dist\lib\toolbox\common2.js:48:22)
    at new CertificateManager (C:\inetpub\AreaTracking\wwwroot\build\node_modules\node-opcua-pki\dist\lib\pki\certificate_manager.js:202:29)
    at new OPCUACertificateManager (C:\inetpub\AreaTracking\wwwroot\build\node_modules\node-opcua-certificate-manager\dist\certificate_manager.js:42:9)
    at getDefaultCertificateManager (C:\inetpub\AreaTracking\wwwroot\build\node_modules\node-opcua-certificate-manager\dist\certificate_manager.js:127:12)
    at new ClientBaseImpl (C:\inetpub\AreaTracking\wwwroot\build\node_modules\node-opcua-client\dist\private\client_base_impl.js:296:114)
    at new OPCUAClientImpl (C:\inetpub\AreaTracking\wwwroot\build\node_modules\node-opcua-client\dist\private\opcua_client_impl.js:287:9)
    at OPCUAClient.create (C:\inetpub\AreaTracking\wwwroot\build\node_modules\node-opcua-client\dist\opcua_client.js:10:16)
    at file:///C:/inetpub/AreaTracking/wwwroot/build/server/chunks/_server-bf75dda4.js:58:28
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25) {
  errno: -4075,
  code: 'EEXIST',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Roaming\\node-opcua-default-nodejs\\Config\\PKI'
}

Since it is IIS I think it does not have access to this folder. I have tried to save the pki files in the same directory as the +server.js file that is reading these values. But I am still getting the same error. I can see the PKI files are being generated on the server but it does not seem to be reading from the generated files. Here is the +server.js file that is reading these values and genereating the pki files.
import {
    OPCUAClient,
    AttributeIds,
    UserTokenType,
    MessageSecurityMode,
    SecurityPolicy,
    OPCUACertificateManager
} from 'node-opcua';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';

const opcServerEndpoint = "endpoint";
const username = "USR";
const password = "PWD";

// Get the directory path of the current module file
const currentDir = new URL('.', import.meta.url).pathname;

// Resolve the pki directory relative to the current module file
const pkiDir = path.resolve(currentDir.slice(1), 'pki');

// Log the PKI directory path for debugging purposes
console.log('PKI directory:', pkiDir);

// Ensure the PKI directory exists or create it if it doesn't
try {
    fs.mkdirSync(pkiDir, { recursive: true });
    console.log('PKI directory created successfully');
} catch (err) {
    console.error('Error creating PKI directory:', err);
}

// Check if certificate files exist, and generate them if not
if (!fs.existsSync(path.join(pkiDir, 'own', 'cert.pem'))) {
    console.log('Generating certificate files...');
    const certificateManager = new OPCUACertificateManager({
        rootFolder: pkiDir, // Specify the root folder for certificate management
        keySize: 2048, // Set the key size for certificate generation
        // Specify the location for storing generated certificates
        // @ts-ignore
        location: path.join(pkiDir, 'own'),
    });
    // Initialize the certificate manager
    certificateManager.initialize()
        .then(() => console.log('Certificate files generated successfully'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error generating certificate files:', err));
}

// Initialize the OPC UA client options
const clientOptions = {
    applicationName: "RejectTrackingClient", // Specify the name of the application
    endpointMustExist: true, // Ensure that the specified endpoint exists
    securityMode: MessageSecurityMode.SignAndEncrypt, // Set the security mode
    securityPolicy: SecurityPolicy.Basic256Sha256, // Set the security policy
    connectionStrategy: {
        maxRetry: 5, // Maximum number of connection retries
        initialDelay: 1000, // Initial delay before the first connection retry (in milliseconds)
        maxDelay: 10000 // Maximum delay between connection retries (in milliseconds)
    },
    // Specify the certificate manager to use for secure communication
    certificateManager: new OPCUACertificateManager({
        automaticallyAcceptUnknownCertificate: true, // Automatically accept unknown certificates
        rootFolder: pkiDir, // Set the root folder for certificate management
        keySize: 2048, // Set the key size for certificate generation
        // Specify the location for storing generated certificates
        // @ts-ignore
        location: path.join(pkiDir, 'own'),
    }),
};

const client = OPCUAClient.create(clientOptions);

/**
 * @type {import("node-opcua").ClientSession | null}
 */
let session = null;
let isConnected = false;
/**
 * @type {string | number | NodeJS.Timeout | null | undefined}
 */
let inactivityTimer = null;

async function initializeOpcClient() {
    try {
        if (!client) {
            // Create the OPC UA client with proper security settings
            // @ts-ignore
            client = OPCUAClient.create({
                endpointMustExist: true,
                securityMode: MessageSecurityMode.SignAndEncrypt,
                securityPolicy: SecurityPolicy.Basic256Sha256,
                connectionStrategy: {
                    maxRetry: 5,
                    initialDelay: 1000,
                    maxDelay: 10000
                },
                // @ts-ignore
                certificateManager: new OPCUACertificateManager({
                    keySize: 2048,
                    // @ts-ignore
                    location: pkiDir
                })
            });

            // Enable detailed logging
            client.on("backoff", (retry, delay) => {
                console.log(`Retrying to connect to ${opcServerEndpoint}, attempt ${retry}, next attempt in ${delay / 1000} seconds`);
            });
        }

        console.log('Connecting to OPC UA server...');
        await client.connect(opcServerEndpoint);
        console.log('Connected to OPC UA server');
        isConnected = true;

        // Create a session with username and password
        console.log('Creating session...');
        session = await client.createSession({
            userName: username,
            password: password,
            type: UserTokenType.UserName
        });
        console.log('Session created');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error initializing OPC UA client:', error);
        // @ts-ignore
        throw new Error(`Failed to initialize OPC UA client: ${error.message}`);
    }
}


async function closeOpcClient() {
    try {
        if (session) {
            await session.close();
            session = null;
            console.log('Session closed');
        }
        if (client) {
            await client.disconnect();
            // @ts-ignore
            client = null;
            console.log('Client disconnected');
        }
        isConnected = false;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error closing OPC UA client:', error);
    }
}

function resetInactivityTimer() {
    if (inactivityTimer) {
        clearTimeout(inactivityTimer);
    }
    inactivityTimer = setTimeout(async () => {
        console.log('Inactivity timeout reached, closing connection...');
        await closeOpcClient();
    }, 25000); // 25 seconds
}

async function readOpcData() {
    try {
        // Ensure the client and session are initialized and connected
        if (!isConnected || !session) {
            await initializeOpcClient();
        }

        // Define an array of nodeIds to read
        const nodeIds = [
            "ns=2;s=POS_1_ID",
            "ns=2;s=POS_1_LEN",
            "ns=2;s=POS_1_TCK",
            "ns=2;s=POS_1_WIDTH"
        ];

        // Perform read operations for each nodeId
        const tagValues = [];
        for (const nodeId of nodeIds) {
            const nodeToRead = {
                nodeId: nodeId,
                attributeId: AttributeIds.Value,
            };
            // @ts-ignore
            const dataValue = await session.read(nodeToRead);

            // Convert Int8Array to string if the value is an array of numbers
            if (Array.isArray(dataValue.value.value) && dataValue.value.value.every(val => typeof val === 'number')) {
                const stringValue = dataValue.value.value.map(val => String.fromCharCode(val)).join('');
                tagValues.push(stringValue);
            } else {
                tagValues.push(dataValue.value.value);
            }
        }

        return tagValues;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in readOpcData:', error);
        // @ts-ignore
        throw new Error(`Failed to read OPC data: ${error.message}`);
    } finally {
        // Reset the inactivity timer after a successful read
        resetInactivityTimer();
    }
}

export async function GET() {
    try {
        const data = await readOpcData();
        console.log(data);
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ data }), { status: 200 });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in GET handler:', error);
        if (error instanceof Error) {
            return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: error.message }), { status: 500 });
        } else {
            return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: "An unknown error occurred" }), { status: 500 });
        }
    }
}

// Graceful shutdown
process.on('SIGINT', async () => {
    console.log('Received SIGINT, shutting down gracefully...');
    try {
        await closeOpcClient();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during shutdown:', error);
    } finally {
        process.exit(0);
    }
});

process.on('SIGTERM', async () => {
    console.log('Received SIGTERM, shutting down gracefully...');
    try {
        await closeOpcClient();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during shutdown:', error);
    } finally {
        process.exit(0);
    }
});


